# Перемещение окна без рамки

Tags: qt

Как перемещать окно за QWidget и QLabel нужно как-то сделать чтобы оно премещалось
только тогда когда пользователь перемещает его за QWidget или QLabel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314429/select-moving-qwidget-in-the-screen ; Если кратко, то перегрузись `mouseMoveEvent ()` и двигать окно через `QWidget::move()`.

Comment: Да, в данном случае проще будет сделать [*EventFiler*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters)

Comment: А пример можно а то я не очень хороший Qt'ист

Comment: дык, по ссылкам же есть примеры... или чего-то именно не понятно?